# Why the zero-order term in a variational transformation of coordinates should be identically the same as the old coordinates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

In the Ref.[[1](http://download.library1.org/main/843000/bd310587d6573e36c750682808a28266/Dwight%20E.%20Neuenschwander%20-%20Emmy%20Noether%E2%80%99s%20Wonderful%20Theorem-Johns%20Hopkins%20U.%20P.%20%282011%29.djvu), page 61] the author proposes that transformations between two coordinate systems can be described by a continuous parameter $\varepsilon$ such that when $\varepsilon=0$ the original coordinates are recovered.

The mapping between these two systems imply the existence of functions $T$ and $Q$ such that
\begin{align}
t\rightarrow t^\prime &=T\big(t,q^\mu,\varepsilon\big),\tag{4.1.1}\label{eq1}\\
q^\mu\rightarrow {q^\prime}^\mu &=Q^\mu\big(t,q^\nu,\varepsilon\big).\tag{4.1.2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}

The author states that if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, then we can to expand the functions $T$ and $Q$ in Taylor series about $\varepsilon=0$, such that:
\begin{align}
t^\prime &=t+\varepsilon\bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}+O\big(\varepsilon^2\big),\tag{4.1.7}\label{eq7}\\
{q^\prime}^\mu &=q^\mu+\varepsilon\bigg(\frac{\partial Q^\mu}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}+O\big(\varepsilon^2\big),\tag{4.1.8}\label{eq8} 
\end{align}
where the author the author identifies $t^\prime=t$ and ${q^\prime}^\mu=q^\mu$ when $\varepsilon=0$.

Also, according to the author, the coefficients of $\varepsilon$ to the first power are called the ''generators'' of the transformation and they can be denoted by
\begin{align}
\tau &\equiv\bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}=\tau\big(t,q^\mu\big),\tag{4.1.9}\label{eq9}\\
\zeta^\mu &\equiv\bigg(\frac{\partial Q^\mu}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}=\zeta^\mu\big(t,q^\mu\big).\tag{4.1.10}\label{eq10}
\end{align}

Now, let me introduce how I'm seeing the problem. The Taylor series expansion around $\varepsilon = 0$ are written as
\begin{align}
T\left(  t,q^{\mu},\varepsilon\right)    & =T\left(  t,q^{\mu},0\right)
+\left(  \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\varepsilon}\right)  _{\varepsilon
=0}+O\left(  \varepsilon^{2}\right),  \\
Q^\mu\left(  t,q^{\mu},\varepsilon\right)    & =Q^\mu\left(  t,q^{\mu},0\right)
+\left(  \dfrac{\partial Q^\mu}{\partial\varepsilon}\right)  _{\varepsilon
=0}+O\left(  \varepsilon^{2}\right).
\end{align}
But, according to the author, on the left side, we have $t^\prime=T\big(t,q^\mu,\varepsilon\big)$ and ${q^\prime}^\mu=Q^\mu(t,qν,\varepsilon\big)$. On the other hand, on the right side, the zero-order term is $t=T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ and $q^\mu=Q^\mu(t,q^\mu,0\big)$, while the first order term $\tau\big(t,q^\mu\big)=\big(\partial T/\partial\varepsilon\big)_{\varepsilon=0}$ and $\zeta^\mu\big(t,q^\nu\big)=\big(\partial Q^\mu/\partial\varepsilon\big)_{\varepsilon=0}$.

My question is centered on the zero-order term because I think that instead of being $T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)=t$ and $Q^\mu\big(t,q^\nu,0\big)=q^\mu$ it should be $T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)=\mathcal{T}\big(t,q^\mu\big)$ and $Q^\mu\big(t,q^\nu,0\big)=\mathcal{Q}^\mu\big(t,q^\nu\big)$ since we are searching for the most general form possible.

**So, what should be the argument for making a more restrictive choice such as $T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)=t$ and $Q^\mu\big(t,q^\nu,0\big)=q^\mu$?**

In my opinion, Eqs. \eqref{eq7} and \eqref{eq8} should be written as
\begin{align}
t^\prime &=\mathcal{T}\big(t,q^\mu\big)+\varepsilon\tau\big(t,q^\mu\big)+O\big(\varepsilon^2\big),\tag{B1}\label{eqB1}\\
{q^\prime}^\mu &=\mathcal{Q}^\mu\big(t,q^\mu\big)+\varepsilon\zeta^\mu\big(t,q^\mu\big)+O\big(\varepsilon^2\big).\tag{B2}\label{eqB2} 
\end{align}

$^{[1]}$ [Dwight E. Neuenschwander, Emmy Noether's Wonderful Theorem](http://download.library1.org/main/843000/bd310587d6573e36c750682808a28266/Dwight%20E.%20Neuenschwander%20-%20Emmy%20Noether%E2%80%99s%20Wonderful%20Theorem-Johns%20Hopkins%20U.%20P.%20%282011%29.djvu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace eqs. (4.1.1) and (4.1.2) by your (A) equations you actually kill the extra parameter introduced $\varepsilon$, rendering the rest of the chapter pointless.

The "generator" term comes from group theory, and in page 64 you find a very brief note: "[...] Because a set of such transformations has an identity element and each transformation has an inverse, the transformations form a group [...]".

And $t'=t$ holds in the limiting case $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, from where you can deduce the form of your function $\mathcal{T}$ not to include $q^\mu$, and $\mathcal{Q}$ not to include $t$.

Look at example in equation (4.1.3) with $\varepsilon$ being a rotation angle about the $z$ axis, how would a series expansion for $t'$ look like in that case?

Comment: Excuse me, maybe my question stayed a bit confusing. Let me clarify. The Taylor expansion of the T and Q functions around ε=0 should be
\begin{align}
T\left(  t,q^{\mu},\varepsilon\right)    & =T\left(  t,q^{\mu},0\right)
+\left(  \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\varepsilon}\right)  _{\varepsilon
=0}+O\left(  \varepsilon^{2}\right)  \\
Q\left(  t,q^{\mu},\varepsilon\right)    & =Q\left(  t,q^{\mu},0\right)
+\left(  \dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial\varepsilon}\right)  _{\varepsilon
=0}+O\left(  \varepsilon^{2}\right),
\end{align}
thats ok!

Comment: But, according to the author, on the left side, we have $t^\prime=T\big(t,q^\mu,\varepsilon\big)$ and ${q^\prime}^\mu=Q^\mu\big(t,q^\nu,\varepsilon\big)$. On the other hand, on the right side, the zero order term is $t = T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ and $q^\mu = Q^\mu=\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$, while the first order term $\tau\big(t,q^\mu\big)=\bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}$ and $\zeta^\mu\big(t,q^\nu\big)=\bigg(\frac{\partial Q^\mu}{\partial\varepsilon}\bigg)_{\varepsilon=0}$.

Comment: My question is centered on the zero-order term because I think that instead of being $t = T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ and $q^\mu = Q^\mu\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ it should be $\mathcal{T}\big(t,q^\mu\big) = T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ and $\mathcal{Q}^\mu\big(t,q^\nu\big) = T\big(t,q^\nu,0\big)$ since we are searching for the most general form possible. So, what should be the argument for making a more restrictive choice such as $t = T\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$ and $q^\mu = Q^\mu\big(t,q^\mu,0\big)$?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

After some reflection, I think I came to an understanding of what should be the answer to the problem. Transformations \eqref{eqB1} and \eqref{eqB2} should be viewed not only as transformations between coordinates but also as perturbations around the original coordinates such that at the boundary where $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ these must be retrieved to recover. In this sense, in order for such a criterion to be satisfied, we must choose (or configure) the functions $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{Q}^\mu$ as $\mathcal{T}\big(t,q^\mu\big) = t$ and $\mathcal{Q}^\mu\big(t,q^\mu\big) = q^\mu$.

Basically, I think this is the same answer that @fredwhileshavin wanted to give in the previous post, but in a veiled way.

Well, I think I'm on the right track for a good answer, but I leave it to the community for judgment.

Comment: Yes, this is the general idea. By hyopthesis we must recover the original value of the coordinates for *some* value of $\varepsilon$, which we may as well take to be $0$.