# Does it make sense to speak in a total derivative of a functional? Part III

Tags: mathematical-physics, field-theory, education, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

In this third part of the series, I will continue the deduction of Noether's theorem initiated in the previous post - [Does it make sense to speak in a total derivative of a functional? Part II](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/474277/does-it-make-sense-to-speak-in-a-total-derivative-of-a-functional-part-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1).

### **Situation 1**

Here, I will consider the validity of the total derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dx^{μ}}
=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partialφ_{r}}\partial_{\mu}φ_{r}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\big(\partial_{ν}φ_{r}\big)}\partial_{\mu}\big(\partial_{ν}φ_{r}\big)+∂_{μ}\mathcal{L}.\tag{III.1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

We have expressed in Eq. (\ref{eq24}) of the previous post ([Does it make sense to speak in a total derivative of a functional? Part II](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474277/228871)) that
\begin{multline}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon} \approx \int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left\{
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}\zeta_{r} + \dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\nu}\zeta_{r}\right. \\ \left. + \xi^{\mu
}\left(  \dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi
_{r}+\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu
}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}+\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L}\right)  +\partial_{\mu}%
\xi^{\mu}\mathcal{L}\right\}, \tag{II. 24}\label{eq24}%
\end{multline}
where I'd like to remember that $\zeta_r\equiv\zeta_r(x)$ and $\xi^{\mu}\equiv\xi^{\mu}(x)$.

If what we ask about Eq. (I.$9$) in the first post of this Series ([Does it make sense to speak in a total derivative of a functional? Part I](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474132/228871)) has a yes as an answer, then the following identifications must be valid: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\zeta_{r}}{dx^{\mu}}=\partial_{\mu}\zeta_{r} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{d\xi^{\mu}}{dx^{\mu}}=\partial_{\mu}\xi^{\mu}.\tag{III.2}
\end{equation}
 Thus, the Eq. (\ref{eq24}) becomes
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left\{
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}\zeta_{r}+\dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\dfrac{d\zeta_{r}}{dx^{\nu}}
+\xi^{\mu}\dfrac{d\mathcal{L}}{dx^{\mu}}+\mathcal{L}\dfrac{d\xi^{\mu}}
{dx^{\mu}}\right\}.\tag{III.3}\label{eq3}
\end{equation}
Now, we do use of identity
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}} \dfrac{d\zeta_{r}}{dx^{\mu}}=\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\left(\zeta_{r}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}
}{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}}\right)-\zeta_{r}\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}},\tag{III.4}\label{eq4}
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left\{
\left(\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}-\dfrac{d}{dx^{\nu} }\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\right)  \zeta
_{r}+\dfrac{d}{dx^{\nu}}\left(  \zeta_{r}\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}+\xi^{\mu}\mathcal{L}\right)  \right\},\tag{III.5}\label{eq5}
\end{equation}
where we have used
\begin{equation}
\xi^{\mu}\dfrac{d\mathcal{L}}{dx^{\mu}}+\mathcal{L}\dfrac{d\xi^{\mu}}{dx^{\mu
}}=\dfrac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\left(  \xi^{\mu}\mathcal{L}\right).
\end{equation}

We have to said in [Does it make sense to speak in a total derivative of a functional? Part II](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474277/228871), Eq.(\ref{II19}), that
\begin{equation}
\zeta_{r}\left(  x\right)  +\xi^{\mu
}\left(  x\right)  \partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}\left(  x\right)
=\dfrac{\tilde{\delta}\phi_{r}}{\varepsilon}=\chi_{r}\left(  x\right) ,\tag{II.19}\label{II19}
\end{equation}
so that (\ref{eq5}) becomes
\begin{multline}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left(
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}-\dfrac{d}{dx^{\nu}}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\right)  \zeta
_{r}\\ +\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\dfrac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\left[  \dfrac
{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}}\chi_{r}-\left(
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\nu}
\phi_{r}-\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}\mathcal{L}\right)  \xi^{\nu}\right].\tag{III.6}\label{eq6}
\end{multline}

And now comes the question: **how can we apply the generalized divergence theorem in the second integral on the right side-hand if instead of a partial derivative we have a total derivative?**

### **Situation 2**

Before asking the question, let's see what happens if we do not use Eq. (\ref{eq1}). In this case, we can rewrite the Eq. (\ref{eq24}) as:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left\{
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}\chi_{r}+\dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\left(  \partial_{\nu}\zeta
_{r}+\xi^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}\right)  +\partial_{\nu
}\left(  \xi^{\nu}\mathcal{L}\right)  \right\},\tag{III.7}\label{eq7}
\end{equation}
where we have used (\ref{II19}).

If we add and subtract the term $\partial_{\mu}
\phi_{r}\partial_{\nu}\xi^{\mu}$ in the expression in parentheses of the second term, that last equation becomes
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left\{
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}\chi_{r}+\dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\nu}\chi_{r}
-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}
\phi_{r}\partial_{\nu}\xi^{\mu}+\partial_{\nu}\left(  \xi^{\nu}\mathcal{L}
\right)  \right\}.\tag{III.8}
\end{equation}
Now, using the identities
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\nu}
\chi_{r}&=\partial_{\nu}\left(  \chi_{r}\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}
{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\right)  -\chi_{r}\partial_{\nu}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}},\tag{III.9}\label{eq9}\\
-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}
\phi_{r}\partial_{\nu}\xi^{\mu}&=-\partial_{\nu}\left(  \dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}\xi^{\mu
}\right)  +\xi^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\left(  \dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}
{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}\right),\tag{III.10}\label{eq10}
\end{align}
we obtain
\begin{multline}
\dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}
}d^{D}x~\xi^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\left(  \dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}
{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}\right)+\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\left(
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}-\partial_{\nu}\dfrac
{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\right)  \chi_{r}
\\+ \int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\partial_{\nu}\left[  \dfrac{\partial
\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\chi_{r}-\left(  \dfrac
{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi
_{r}-\xi^{\nu}\mathcal{L}\right)  \xi^{\mu}\right].\tag{III.11}\label{eq11}
\end{multline}

Here, considering the validity of Euler-Lagrange's equation
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{r}}-\partial_{\nu}\dfrac
{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}=0, \tag{III.12}\label{eq12}
\end{equation}
and the applicability of divergence theorem over to third integral (**Which now seems to be quite reasonable!**)
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\partial_{\nu}J^{\nu}=\oint_{\partial
\mathbb{\Omega}}dS_{\nu}~J^{\nu}=0,\tag{III.13}\label{eq13}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
J^{\nu}=\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}}\chi
_{r}-\left(  \dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}\phi_{r}
}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}-\delta_{\mu}^{\nu}\mathcal{L}\right)  \xi^{\mu},\tag{III.14}\label{eq14}
\end{equation}
when $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$, we have found
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx\int_{\mathbb{\Omega}}d^{D}x~\xi^{\mu
}\partial_{\nu}\left(  \dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_{\nu}
\phi_{r}}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{r}\right),\tag{III.15}\label{eq15}
\end{equation}
which at first seems to be non-zero.

As we know, it is hoped that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{S^{\prime}-S}{\varepsilon}\approx 0.\tag{III.16}\label{eq16}
\end{equation}

### **Questions**

We have, therefore, two questions:

1. In the situation (1), when we use the total derivative (\ref{eq1}), the divergence theorem seems nonapplicable over the second integral of the Eq. (\ref{eq6}), so the question is: **Is it still possible to apply the divergence theorem the second integral (Eq.(\ref{eq6}))?**
2. In the situation (2), when we do not use the total derivative, we have a remaining term that is apparently is not null. The question is: **Could this term become null? What does it really represent?**

Of course, I am considering a possibility of that I have committed some mistake in all the way follow at here, but, at the point of view mathematical, all my calculations seem to be correct. I would be very grateful if anyone could see something besides what I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning situation 1, the main point seems to be that the generalized divergence theorem works with total derivatives, not partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

According to the conclusions obtained from [Part II](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/477823/228871), we have concluded that situation 1 is, in fact, the correct situation and there, in the second integral of equation \eqref{eq6}, it is valid to make use of the divergence theorem, since it is a total partial derivative.