# Why does the action appear in the propagator in the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, operators, path-integral, propagator

According to modern quantum mechanics by Sakuria, Feynman's path integral formulation of classical mechanics was motivated by a statement in Dirac's book:
$$exp\left(i\int^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}}\frac{dt\;L_{classical}(x,\dot{x})}{\hbar}\right)\;\text{corresponds to}\;\langle x_{2},t_{2}|x_{1},t_{1}\rangle$$ where $\langle x_{2},t_{2}|x_{1},t_{1}\rangle$ can be interpreted as the probability amplitude for a particle prepared at $t_{1}$ with position eigenvalue $x_{1}$  to be found at later time $t_{2}$ at position $x_{2}$. I can't find any justification for this expression in any of the sources I've read on the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics. The closest I've come was a paper written by Dirac (https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Dirac33.pdf), however I struggled to make sense of it. I feel  comfortable with path integral formulation taking this as a given, so my question is why does the action appear in an exponential in this way to represent the transition amplitude?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701069/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616186/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516831/2451 and links therein.